# Getting ValueError: Input != Target while using model.fit_generator

Tags: python, keras, generator, valueerror

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 6 input samples and 128 target samples.

when training with keras.
I am using a generator to generate a moving window over my timeseries that looks like this:

```
def generator_val(X,y,number_of_steps, batch_size=128, length=300, overview_steps = 300, shuffle=True, prediction = False):
    while 1:  
        machine_idcs = np.concatenate(
        [np.repeat(i, len(np.arange(length, Xi.shape[0], overview_steps))) for i, Xi in enumerate(X)])
        # Generate all indicies for all possible steps.
        step_idcs = np.concatenate(
        [np.arange(length, Xi.shape[0], overview_steps) for Xi in X])

        # We create a matrix of indices from which we sample for the mini
        # batches.
        examples = np.zeros((len(step_idcs), 2), dtype=np.int32)
        examples[:, 0] = machine_idcs
        examples[:, 1] = step_idcs

        for i in range(0, examples.shape[0], batch_size):
            # Get the machine and step indices of the mini-batch.
            mbatch = examples[i:i + batch_size]

            # Preinitialize the mini batch.
            sequence = np.zeros(
                (len(mbatch), length, X[0].shape[1]), np.float32)
            mini_batch_y = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.float32) 

            for j in range(mbatch.shape[0]):
                machine_idx = mbatch[j, 0]
                step_idx = mbatch[j, 1]
                sequence[j] = X[machine_idx][step_idx - length: step_idx]
                mini_batch_y[j] = y[machine_idx][step_idx]
            mini_batch_X = sequence  
            yield mini_batch_X, mini_batch_y
```

To start the training i am using the model.fit_generator:

```
model.fit_generator(generator(X, y, number_of_steps= number_of_steps,batch_size=128, length=300),
                    validation_data = generator(X_val, y_val,   number_of_steps= number_of_steps_val,batch_size=128, length=300),
                    validation_steps = number_of_steps_val, 
                    samples_per_epoch= number_of_steps, 
                    epochs=2)
```

It is like if the generator is not using the infinity loop, or cant reset within one batch?
Is there a possibility to reset the generator after each epoch?

**Update**

```
###sample data
test_X = np.random.rand(len(X),10037, 24).astype(np.float32)
test_Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(len(X),10037)).astype(np.float32)
val_X = np.random.rand(len(X_val), 10037,24).astype(np.float32)
val_Y = np.random.randint(0,1,(len(X_val),10037)).astype(np.float32)

X = [item for item in test_X]
Y = [item for item in test_Y]
X_val = [item for item in val_X]
Y_val = [item for item in val_Y]
```

**Workaround**

I have found a solution for this Error, however i am not really happy with it, because it throws away some of the last sequences. The solution is, that there are as many sequences that the data set can be devided by the batch size.
The code for that looks like this:

```
window_steps = 50
number_of_samples = sum([X_[i].shape[0] for i in range(len(X_))])-len(X_)*300
number_of_steps = int(number_of_samples/128/window_steps)

number_of_samples_val = sum([X_val_[i].shape[0] for i in range(len(X_val_))])-len(X_val_)*300
number_of_steps_val = int(number_of_samples_val/128/window_steps)   

def generator_val(X,y, number_of_steps, window_steps = window_steps, batch_size=128, length=300, overview_steps = 300, shuffle=True, prediction = False):
    while 1:  
        machine_idcs = np.concatenate(
        [np.repeat(i, len(np.arange(length, Xi.shape[0], window_steps))) for i, Xi in enumerate(X)])
        # Generate all indicies for all possible steps.
        step_idcs = np.concatenate(
        [np.arange(length, Xi.shape[0], window_steps) for Xi in X])

        # We create a matrix of indices from which we sample for the mini
        # batches.
        examples = np.zeros((number_of_steps*batch_size, 2), dtype=np.int32)
        examples[:, 0] = machine_idcs[:number_of_steps*batch_size]
        examples[:, 1] = step_idcs[:number_of_steps*batch_size]

        for i in range(0, examples.shape[0], batch_size):
            # Get the machine and step indices of the mini-batch.
            mbatch = examples[i:i + batch_size]

            # Preinitialize the mini batch.
            sequence = np.zeros(
                (len(mbatch), length, X[0].shape[1]), np.float32)
            mini_batch_y = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.float32) 

            for j in range(mbatch.shape[0]):
                machine_idx = mbatch[j, 0]
                step_idx = mbatch[j, 1]
                sequence[j] = X[machine_idx][step_idx - length: step_idx]
                mini_batch_y[j] = y[machine_idx][step_idx]
            mini_batch_X = sequence  
            yield mini_batch_X, mini_batch_y

model.fit_generator(generator_val(X, Y, number_of_steps= number_of_steps, window_steps = window_steps, batch_size=128, length=300),
                    validation_data = generator_val(X_val,Y_val,  number_of_steps= number_of_steps_val,window_steps = window_steps,batch_size=128, length=300),
                    validation_steps = number_of_steps_val, 
                    samples_per_epoch= number_of_steps, 
                    epochs=2)
```

And here is a sample network for it:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(sequence_length, num_features))
h1 = LSTM(50)(input1)
prediction = Dense(1)(h1)
model = Model(inputs=[input1], outputs=[prediction])
loss = "binary_crossentropy"
optimizer = "adam"   
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

So, do you know how to use all Sequences without throwing some away?

Comment: Are you sure your code is ok? I don't see you defining `mini_batch_X` anywhere. But the problem is this: `mini_batch_X.shape[0]` must be equal to `mini_batch_y.shape[0]`.

Comment: Oh sorry, added the line     mini_batch_X = sequence, had to shorten the code a little bit.

Comment: Can you create some fake data... `np.randon.rand(?,?)` and just format it like that with the proper shape for X and Y

Comment: Done that and added a unsatisfying solution also, where some sequences are thrown away.